# C Pthread: Running only 10 threads simultaneously (what is the problem here)

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads, mutex

So I'm very new to the whole concept of pthread in C but please hear me out. I have the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <unistd.h>


static pthread_mutex_t  mutex = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;

static pthread_cond_t   endCond = PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER;
static pthread_cond_t   startCond = PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER;

void * threadThingy(void * n){
    pthread_cond_wait(&startCond, &mutex);
    printf("%d: RAND: %d\n", *((int*)n), rand());

    //Lock mutex before broadcasting to main thread
    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
    pthread_cond_broadcast(&endCond);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);


    free(n);
    fflush(stdout);
    return 0;
}


int main(void){
    printf("Starting\n");
    pthread_t threads[100];
    int i = 0;

    while(i < 10){
        int *arg = malloc(sizeof(int));
        *arg = i;
        pthread_create(&threads[i], NULL, threadThingy, arg);
        i++;
    }

    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
    pthread_cond_broadcast(&startCond);

    int finished = 0;

    while(finished <= 100){
        pthread_cond_wait(&endCond, &mutex);

        //Lock mutex so no other requests can come in
        pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
        finished++;

        int *arg = malloc(sizeof(int));
        *arg = 11;
        pthread_create(threads[i], NULL, threadThingy, arg);
        i++;
        pthread_cond_broadcast(&startCond);
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);

    }

    printf("Stopping\n");

    sleep(1000);
}
```

The whole goal is to run (only) 10 threads simultaneously of the 100. My idea was to start 10 threads, than wait until one is finished and start another one. So I let the program wait until a thread returns, then I start a new one so the thread that just returned gets replaced. What have I missed? Because now I only get this as an output:

> Starting 
>   0: RAND: 1804289383

Comment: Would it not be easier/simpler to just load a semaphore with 10 units, create 100 threads, have them all wait at their start for a semaphore unit, then post back the unit just before they exit?  It's easy to get into a tangle with threads if you don't go for the simplest design that will clearly work:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned by Lavigne958, in function threadThingy() there is deadlock caused by pthread_cond_wait() as it will acquire the lock. Again, you are trying to lock it in next line. This is causing deadlock.

There are a few things need to check:

1. You need to lock the mutex before calling pthread_cond_wait().
2. If you solve the above issue, using multiple condition variable with the same mutex may cause further deadlock.
3. If you are not joining the threads, it will be better to create detached threads using PTHREAD_CREATE_DETACHED attribute.
4. The problem of N number of threads running simultaneously can be solved with one semaphore OR one condition variable(and one mutex). Example with semaphore is given below.

   ```
   #include <stdio.h>
   #include <pthread.h>
   #include <semaphore.h>
   #include <unistd.h>

   sem_t mysem;
   #define NUM_CONCURRENT_THREADS 4
   #define MAX_THREADS 40

   void *thread(void *arg)
   {
           printf("Thread id %ld: started\n", pthread_self());
           sleep(5); // Do some work
           printf("Thread id %ld: Exiting\n", pthread_self());
           sem_post(&mysem);
           return NULL;
   }


   int main()
   {
           pthread_t t[MAX_THREADS];
           pthread_attr_t attr;
           int rc, i = 0;

           sem_init(&mysem, 0, NUM_CONCURRENT_THREADS);
           rc = pthread_attr_init(&attr);
           rc = pthread_attr_setdetachstate(&attr, PTHREAD_CREATE_DETACHED);

           printf("\nParent begin\n");
           while(i < MAX_THREADS)
           {
                   sem_wait(&mysem);
                   pthread_create(&t[i], &attr, thread, NULL);
                   i++;
           }
           printf("\nParent end.\n");

           sem_destroy(&mysem);
           return 0;
   }
   ```

Please check blog [Tech Easy](http://techeasyblogs.blogspot.com/) for more information on threads.

Answer (score 0):

in the function that your threads run, you start by waiting on a condition but you forgot to take the mutex before. So you first must take the mutex before waiting on the condition.

you have what we call a deadlock.

What happens is:

1. the first thread wakes up (the pthread_con_wait function acquires the lock for you already)
2. then you try to acquire the lock again => deadlock because you already own the lock so you kinda deadlock yourself.